# How to cancel the import of a module if an error occurs?

Tags: powershell

I've got a PowerShell module that sets 5 variables with module scope like so:

```
Set-Variable DatabaseName     -Option Constant -Value "DbName"
Set-Variable DomainName       -Option Constant -Value "DomainName"
Set-Variable ServerInstance   -Option Constant -Value "Server\Instance"
Set-Variable Server           -Option ReadOnly -Value (New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server $ServerInstance)
Set-Variable Database         -Option ReadOnly -Value ($Server.Databases[$DatabaseName])
```

If these variables aren't set properly, the whole module basically falls over and nothing will work.

The only way I can check the variables have been set property is checking if `$Database` is null. However this code:

`if ($Database -eq $null)
{
    Write-Error 'Variables not set.'
    Remove-Module ModuleName
}`

doesn't work because the module hasn't been completed imported yet.

Using the `throw` keyword gives me this error, which doesn't really explain what went wrong:

```
import-module : The module to process 'Module.psm1', listed in
field 'ModuleToProcess/RootModule' of module manifest 'C:\Users\Me\My Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Module\Module.psd1' was not
processed because no valid module was found in any module directory.
At line:1 char:1
+ import-module Module
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (Module:String) [Import-Module], PSInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleFileNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
```

What is the 'correct' way to abort the import of a module in PowerShell?

Comment: I think you should design your module in a way that its always valid so there is no need to cancel the import of a module. What is your root problem?

Comment: What do you suggest? The only thing that comes to mind is providing cmdlets for the user to set the values of the variables themselves.

Comment: It depends on your needs. But if you have a function that for example executes a sql query, I would give that function a databasecontext object (e. g. hashtable) containing the connection information and pass it for each function call rather than access module-scope variables containing these informations

Comment: Instead of trying to use `Remove-Module` you could use the error as a notification that you need to correct the problem and reimport again?

Comment: @Matt, that's what I had originally. I'm looking at another solution involving the end user setting the values and I'll see which option my superior prefers better.

Comment: In case this is an X/Y problem. What is wrong with your variables in the first place where this becomes an issue. Perhaps addressing your _real_ issue might be a better idea.

Comment: Basically, if the DatabaseName, DomainName and ServerInstance variables aren't set correctly, none of the other cmdlets would work because they'd try to reference objects that were either null or initialised incorrectly and then throw errors. I've just reread Kamo's answer and realised a better way to address this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't you use `try/catch` functionality?

```
Try
{
    // DO your import
}
Catch
{
    $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
    $FailedItem = $_.Exception.ItemName
    Break
}
```

Comment: I could, but I'm not importing this inside a script. It's straight from the powershell prompt. Writing a big one line try/catch block seems a bit excessive.

Comment: Just looked back at this answer and I totally misunderstood what Kamo was saying. But now it makes perfect sense.